# Examples of Lattices of Sp(n,1)

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

$Sp(n,1)$ is the isometry group of $n$-dimensional quaternionic hyperbolic space. It is written in literature that the group is an example of a hyperbolic groups. Can you suggest me any reference where the proof has been provided. Basically I want to know an explicit example of a finitely generated, discrete hyperbolic group which has Kazhdan's Property (T).

Since the group $Sp(n,1)$ has property (T) i.e. any conditionally negative definite function on the group will be bounded. So any uniform lattice will be an example of what I want. But unfortunately, I don't know this kind of groups will be like.

Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the $n=1$ case, i.e. $\text{Sp}(1, 1) = \text{Spin}(4, 1)$?

Comment: But $Sp(n,1)$ has Property (T) for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: see e.g. "Quaternionic hyperbolic lattices of minimal covolume" by Emery and Kim, https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07776. To your more general question of explicit hyperbolic groups with property (T), see "Hyperbolic generalized triangle groups, property (T) and finite simple quotients" by Caprace,  Conder, Kaluba, Witzel who construct fairly small explicit presentations.

Comment: By rigidity results of Corlette and Gromov-Schoen, lattices in $\mathrm{Sp}(n,1)$ are arithmetic. I'm not very comfortable with quaternions, but I think the following works (this is a variation on the standard example of an arithmetic hyperbolic lattice): take $\Gamma$ the group of squared matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2, i, j, k]$ and preserving the quaternionic form $q_1 \bar q_1 + \ldots + q_n \bar q_n - \sqrt 2 q_{n+1} \bar q_{n+1}$. Then $\Gamma$ is conjugate to a lattice in $\mathrm{Sp}(n,1)$.

Comment: Explicit presentations of non-uniform lattices are given here: https://msp.org/agt/2022/22-8/p02.xhtml These are relatively hyperbolic, and relative hyperbolic filling will give quotients which are hyperbolic and have property (T). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-006-0012-3 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-008-1070-6

Comment: Other fairly explicit examples of hyperbolic groups with property (T) are given here: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3941466

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09276